# Xcode -- Linker warning with library -- Debug-iphonesimulator vs. Debug-iphoneos

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, linker-warning

I am building a project with a library.  The version I am making is the debug version.  The library builds itself into the following directory:

LibraryPath/build/Debug-iphoneos

When I am linking my main project, I get the following warning:

Directory 'LibraryPath/build/Debug-iphonesimulator' following -L not found

Xcode finds everything, and the build works just fine, but the warning is annoying.  How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 5):

Check the properties for the application Target and the Build Locations Per-configuration paths.

Comment: In both projects, it is $(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)  The EFFECTIVE

Comment: @WilliamJockusch you should make this comment the actual answer

Answer (score -1):

The problems was that I had the library set to "Device" and the main project set to "simulator".

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate where you are setting the "Device" and "simulator" variables?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what this means?